# Can I know what was the last step in visual studio 2003 debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

I have to fix asp.net application in visual studio 2003,
Is there a way to see the previous step before the breakpoint?
Thanks!

Comment: Why not put the breakpoint where you want it like one line up or at the beginning of that section of code?

Comment: Are u meaning VS2013 instead of VS2003?

Comment: It's a set function , and I can't find the previous statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a finite number of places where the function can be called.  And since .NET is statically typed, the compiler knows all of them.  Visual Studio 2003 is *ancient* so I'm not 100% familiar with the debugger's capabilities, but there are some things you can try:

- The debugger might have a "call stack" that shows where the call to the function was made.  This would allow you to find the calling code and place a breakpoint there.
- Throwing an exception as a temporary debugging measure will also give you a stack trace to show you what code is calling the function, so you can find it and place a breakpoint there.
- If you right-click on the function name, is there an option to "find all references"?  That would tell you all of the locations in the code which call that function.